# Section 5 Transformation of velocities

Tags: special-relativity

In Landau and Lifshitz's The Classical Theory of Fields, section 5 we start with the given transformations:
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^{2}}},\;v_y=\frac{v'_y\sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{c^2}}}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}},\;v_z=\frac{v'_z\sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{c^2}}}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}}.
$$

Then Landau says

> For a velocity *V* significantly smaller than the velocity of light (the velocity *v* can be arbitrary), we have approximately, to terms order *V/c*:
>   $$
> v_x=v_x'+V(1-\frac{v_x'^2}{c^2}),\;v_y=v_y'-v_y'v_x'\frac{V}{c^2},\;v_z=v_z'-v_z'v_x'\frac{V}{c^2}.
> $$

Is there a typo here?

If by "to terms order *V/c*" means $\;V^2/c^2\rightarrow 0$, then the first three equations look like this:
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^{2}}},\;v_y=\frac{v'_y}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}},\;v_z=\frac{v'_z}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}}.
$$

If I multiply each term by the conjugate of its denominator then the equations look like this:
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^{2}}}\frac{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})},\;v_y=\frac{v'_y}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}}\frac{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})},\;v_z=\frac{v'_z}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}}\frac{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})},
$$

such that there are no cross terms in the denominator:
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{1-v'^2_x\frac{V^2}{c^{4}}},\;v_y=\frac{v'_y(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{1-v'^2_x\frac{V^2}{c^{4}}},\;v_z=\frac{v'_z(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{1-v'^2_x\frac{V^2}{c^{4}}};
$$
 thus if $\;V^2/c^2\rightarrow 0$ then $V^2/c^4 \rightarrow0$:
$$
v_x=v_x'+V(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}),\;v_y=v'_y(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}),\;v_z=v'_z(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2}).
$$

Which is almost the same as the equation within the quote; the only difference is the x-term, which has $v_x'V/c^2$ instead of $v_x'^2/c^2$.

Any thoughts? Could it be a typo? Does anyone have a newer edition? I have the revised second edition. What I think is that this is a typo and that it might have been corrected in the newer editions.

Comment: I had an inkling that the Taylor theorem would work. Thank you. I also made an edit to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you agree with Landau on $v_y$ and $v_z$, so lets focus on $v_x$:

Let $c=1$.

$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V}{1+v_x'V}=(v_x'+V)\frac{1}{1+v_x'V}
$$

Next, use $\frac{1}{1-x}\approx 1+x$ to write the fraction as
$$
\frac{1}{1+v_x'V}\approx 1-v_x'V
$$

Back to $v_x$:
$$
v_x=(v_x'+V)\frac{1}{1+v_x'V}\approx (v_x'+V)(1-v_x'V)=v_x'+V(1-v_x'^2)+\dots
$$
where $\dots=\text{something times $V^2$}$, which is very small. This expression agrees with Landau's.

Note that you were really close to the correct answer, but you forgot some parentheses!! First you wrote
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V}{1+v'_x\frac{V}{c^{2}}}\frac{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}
$$
but after that, this changed into
$$
v_x=\frac{v_x'+V(1-v'_x\frac{V}{c^2})}{1-v'^2_x\frac{V^2}{c^{4}}}
$$
where there is a set of parentheses missing!

Comment: I appreciate you answering my question. Thank you for fleshing out using the Taylor theorem as it is much quicker than the way I worked out!